# How to use verb stem+始める?

Tags: compound-verbs

I know you use *verb stem+始める* when you want to indicate that something started, so would this sentence be correct?

> 特にゲームをする始めます。

Comment: Do you know what a "stem" is?

Comment: Yeah, the dictionary verb stem. Or is it suppose to be the stem of ゲームをし始めます?

Comment: Generally what is the difference between a verb and a verb stem?

Comment: A verb is just the action and a verb stem is for conjugating a verb to polite speech or casual etc Oh wait, suru is not a stem loll so it is shi then.

Answer (score 2):

The conjugation before verb is 連用形(masu-form), so your sentence is incorrect.　ゲームをし始めます is correct. For example, "start walking" is 歩き始める. 歩き is 連用形 of a verb 歩く.

In addition, 特に is unnatural in this sentence.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I wanted to say especially playing at the start of the game. That's why I thought I could use tokuni.